# data cleaning and matching names in r

Tags: r, matching, reshape, reshape2

[image: Dataframe]

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 
63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 
68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
73L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 
84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 
93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 
95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 100L, 
100L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 
105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 107L, 
107L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 
117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 
127L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 134L, 
135L, 136L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 141L, 141L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 146L, 146L, 146L, 
146L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 148L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L), .Label = c("Adam Tharker", "Adam Tharkur", "Alan Hamaoui", 
"Alyssa Sorrells", "Amanda Chamberlin", "Amanda Perez", "Amarilis Garcia", 
"Amarillus Garcia", "Amber Norman", "Anastasia", "Anastasia M", 
"Andrea du Chaussee", "Angel McNeil ", "Angel McNeill", "April", 
"Ariella Sherman", "Ashley Carter", "Ashley Westfall", "Aubrey Gainey", 
"Brandon Vieire", "Brandon Viera", "Briani Hall", "Brianna Franklin", 
"Britani Hall", "Brittany Bodnick", "Brittany Jones", "Caitlin Boline", 
"Caitlyn McKinzie", "Camella", "Camella Ciabaltino", "Candace Conroy", 
"Capri Leskowicz", "Capri Leszkowicz ", "Carlos Castillo", "Carol Sapp", 
"Carole Sapp", "Caroline Gray", "Charnew", "Chelsea Richards", 
"Chelsey Hagar", "Chereka Hamilton", "Chereka Hamilton ", "Christopher Browning", 
"Claire Fairbanks", "Colleen Sheu", "Danielle Weitzel", "Dave Lawson", 
"David Gulden", "Debbie", "Debra Buis", "Dipti Sharma", "Domonique Woods", 
"Eric Price", "Eva Oberllander", "Fallon Flowers", "Gabriella O.", 
"Golbahar", "Hannah S", "Heather Faurote", "Heather Stamm", "Hiba Kaashmiri", 
"Isha Talati", "Isha Tali", "Ivy Byun", "Jackie Flynn", "Jackie Tanner", 
"Jacqueline Villasin", "James Bartlett", "Jane Livingston", "Jena Smith", 
"Jennifer Tyler", "Jennifer Zappola", "Joel Anderson", "Jorge", 
"Julia Manhart", "Juliana Ortagus", "Kara Moulton", "Kate", "Kathleen Endorf", 
"Katie Claxton", "Kay Nowak", "Kenny Totten", "Kerry Berner", 
"Kristen Horton", "Kristen Mercadante", "Kristen Mercadantu", 
"Kristen Rigney", "Kristin", "Kristin Falen", "Kristina Snyder", 
"Krystal Christopher", "Lauren P", "Lauren Patterson", "Lauren Thilmony", 
"Lauren Walker", "Lisa Eade", "Mackenzie McAnaough", "Madeline Alt", 
"Makenzie McAnaugh", "Maria Beregkina", "Maya Arth", "Megan Dowdell", 
"Megan LeClair", "Melissa P", "Michelle Nicholson", "Morgana Wojcik", 
"Naseema Abbasi", "Natasha Sankella", "Nicole Curry", "Nicole Rohner", 
"Niki Dagot", "Nora A", "Pachel Parker", "Rachel", "Rachel ", 
"Rachel Goldberg", "Rachel Irons", "Rachel K.", "Rachel Kosiba", 
"Rachel Parker", "Rebekah Rosen", "Ryan Sever", "Samantha Amick", 
"Sanya Matani", "Sara Ashley Phillips", "Shainna Ali", "Shana King", 
"Shawn Helvey", "Sherry Lehman", "Sim", "Simanto Khandaker", 
"Sofia Moumouris", "Stephanie Cassidy", "Susan M. Riposta", "Susan Riposta", 
"Tamara Nelson", "Taneisha Greenidge", "Tania", "Tara Engold", 
"Taylor Farrell", "Teddy Moumouris", "Thomas Naboris", "Thomas Nabors", 
"Tiffany Miller", "Tori Cole", "Tracy Gammage", "Vanessa Dominguez", 
"Vanessa Hernandez", "Whitney Abernathy", "Zarana Upadhay", "Zarana Upadhyay"
), class = "factor"), Taska = c(24, 26, 27, 26, 26, 28, 18, 16, 
19, 23, 23, 22, 25, 27, 27, 26, 23, 26, 26, 28, 27, 23, 25, 27, 
26, 23, 25, 25, 22, 22, 24, 23, 21, 25, 23, 27, 27, 20, 27, 22, 
24, 28, 27, 26, 28, 28, 27, 28, 21, 21, 20, 27, 25, 25, 25, 28, 
24, 28, 24, 23, 26, 24, 25, 28, 26, 26, 27, 25, 28, 12, 19, 22, 
21, 26, 24, 28, 27, 22, 27, 21, 26, 28, 24, 25, 23, 24, 19, 27, 
27, 26, 24, 24, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 21, 23, 26, 20, 25, 27, 20, 
27, 28, 23, 24, 23, 24, 27, 24, 24, 27, 28, 12, 17, 24, 23, 27, 
28, 28, 22, 23, 28, 20, 24, 27, 26, 24, 28, 23, 28, 28, 22, 25, 
27, 28, 28, 24, 25, 27, 27, 28, 19, 24, 27, 26, 28, 28, 26, 21, 
20, 25, 25, 28, 28, 24, 28, 27, 27, 28, 19, 21, 26, 26, 26, 27, 
28, 28, 22, 26, 16, 26, 28, 28, 26, 26, 27, 26, 19, 28, 28, 28, 
26, 21, 28, 28, 26, 26, 24, 20, 27, 28, 19, 25, 19, 23, 25, 27, 
28, 28, 22, 23, 24, 28, 28, 28, 24, 28, 28, 26, 23, 24, 27, 26, 
27, 28, 23, 26, 27, 28, 28, 19, 17, 22, 23, 25, 25, 27, 28, 17, 
26, 24, 26, 23, 20, 22, 24, 24, 28, 24, 28, 23, 25, 27, 26, 22, 
25, 25, 28, 28, 27, 19, 25, 23, 24, 25, 26, 24, 28, 18, 25, 25, 
27, 27, 28, 23, 27, 28, 23, 28, 27, 21, 24, 27, 28, 28, 28, 20, 
18, 20, 17, 28, 24, 27, 26, 24, 21, 27, 28, 14, 20, 28, 26, 21, 
20, 23, 28, 27, 27, 27, 18, 25, 27, 28, 27, 22, 28, 19, 28, 19, 
20, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 26, 26, 28, 28, 18, 28, 28, 26, 28, 21, 
25, 25, 21, 27, 28, 26, 21, 21, 28, 25, 25, 25, 19, 22, 26, 23, 
9, 23, 16, 25, 25, 27, 24, 23, 27, 28, 27), Bonda = c(24, 25, 
25, 27, 28, 28, 20, 16, 21, 25, 22, 23, 27, 27, 27, 28, 25, 27, 
26, 26, 28, 25, 25, 26, 19, 23, 23, 27, 19, 21, 24, 23, 23, 27, 
28, 27, 28, 20, 26, 23, 27, 28, 28, 25, 28, 26, 28, 28, 15, 28, 
28, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 24, 28, 22, 23, 26, 26, 26, 28, 21, 28, 
28, 26, 27, 14, 22, 21, 23, 25, 24, 24, 26, 28, 25, 22, 27, 28, 
25, 25, 17, 22, 11, 19, 25, 26, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 24, 28, 24, 
24, 26, 21, 25, 26, 24, 28, 28, 21, 20, 25, 25, 28, 22, 26, 23, 
28, 28, 21, 28, 22, 24, 28, 28, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 
28, 23, 28, 28, 23, 28, 28, 28, 28, 23, 25, 26, 28, 28, 21, 27, 
27, 28, 28, 28, 24, 26, 22, 24, 27, 28, 27, 25, 28, 26, 27, 28, 
20, 21, 27, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 23, 28, 20, 27, 27, 27, 25, 27, 
28, 27, 22, 28, 28, 28, 25, 26, 28, 28, 23, 26, 27, 24, 25, 28, 
25, 28, 21, 23, 26, 28, 28, 28, 24, 24, 25, 28, 28, 23, 25, 28, 
28, 26, 24, 24, 24, 28, 28, 26, 17, 18, 27, 28, 28, 21, 22, 24, 
26, 27, 27, 27, 28, 19, 27, 25, 26, 23, 24, 26, 27, 24, 28, 27, 
28, 22, 24, 21, 25, 27, 26, 27, 27, 28, 27, 18, 23, 25, 26, 27, 
27, 28, 28, 22, 22, 26, 27, 27, 27, 24, 25, 28, 26, 27, 28, 23, 
23, 27, 28, 28, 28, 23, 13, 19, 19, 28, 23, 25, 28, 24, 26, 25, 
28, 9, 19, 28, 22, 17, 23, 23, 27, 26, 26, 27, 18, 26, 27, 27, 
26, 25, 28, 20, 28, 20, 23, 27, 27, 22, 27, 26, 28, 25, 28, 22, 
24, 27, 28, 26, 28, 17, 22, 23, 28, 28, 28, 26, 25, 26, 28, 24, 
24, 26, 19, 22, 23, 24, 12, 20, 21, 22, 27, 27, 25, 28, 26, 28, 
18), Goala = c(24, 25, 28, 25, 26, 28, 18, 21, 19, 25, 23, 23, 
28, 27, 27, 23, 26, 26, 24, 27, 28, 16, 27, 27, 21, 24, 23, 28, 
20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 22, 25, 28, 28, 21, 28, 25, 26, 28, 22, 27, 
21, 27, 27, 21, 19, 26, 18, 26, 24, 24, 24, 27, 24, 24, 21, 23, 
23, 25, 21, 22, 28, 27, 27, 26, 26, 17, 22, 24, 23, 24, 26, 18, 
28, 28, 28, 24, 28, 26, 24, 28, 21, 26, 18, 23, 27, 28, 25, 24, 
25, 24, 28, 27, 26, 23, 27, 24, 23, 26, 27, 17, 28, 28, 24, 25, 
24, 25, 28, 23, 26, 28, 28, 20, 18, 25, 24, 27, 27, 28, 22, 26, 
28, 17, 25, 27, 28, 28, 28, 25, 28, 28, 24, 25, 13, 27, 28, 24, 
24, 28, 28, 27, 20, 24, 26, 27, 28, 28, 25, 23, 22, 25, 27, 25, 
25, 23, 28, 27, 28, 28, 22, 21, 21, 26, 28, 28, 28, 28, 24, 27, 
18, 24, 26, 27, 26, 27, 25, 20, 25, 28, 28, 28, 28, 23, 28, 28, 
24, 17, 28, 21, 27, 27, 21, 26, 23, 23, 24, 24, 27, 28, 25, 23, 
21, 28, 28, 27, 26, 27, 25, 25, 22, 25, 28, 28, 28, 28, 24, 28, 
28, 26, 26, 21, 17, 24, 27, 25, 27, 25, 28, 18, 27, 24, 27, 23, 
19, 22, 25, 26, 28, 23, 28, 24, 26, 27, 26, 25, 24, 27, 22, 26, 
28, 22, 24, 24, 25, 27, 27, 25, 27, 21, 25, 27, 27, 27, 24, 25, 
27, 28, 24, 28, 27, 21, 25, 25, 28, 22, 28, 24, 21, 21, 19, 28, 
22, 28, 26, 25, 24, 28, 22, 14, 23, 28, 27, 22, 22, 21, 28, 28, 
26, 27, 21, 27, 21, 22, 25, 21, 20, 18, 28, 24, 23, 26, 27, 23, 
22, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 20, 28, 28, 25, 27, 19, 23, 26, 20, 21, 
28, 27, 18, 22, 16, 27, 24, 26, 23, 24, 26, 25, 17, 22, 18, 21, 
26, 27, 26, 25, 27, 28, 26), Name2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
57L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 
67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 
73L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 
78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 
86L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 
94L, 95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 
104L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
108L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 
117L, 117L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 120L, 121L, 
122L, 122L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 128L, 129L, 
130L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 
136L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 
141L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Adam Tharker", 
"Adam Tharkur", "Alan Hamaoui", "Alyssa Sorrells", "Amanda Chamberlin", 
"Amanda Perez", "Amarilis Garcia", "Amarillus Garcia", "Amber Norman", 
"Anastasia", "Anastasia M", "Andrea du Chaussee", "Angel McNeill", 
"April", "Ariella Sherman", "Ashley Carter", "Ashley Westfall", 
"Aubrey Gainey", "Brandon Vieire", "Brandon Viera", "Briani Hall", 
"Brianna Franklin", "Britani Hall", "Brittany Bodnick", "Brittany Jones", 
"Caitlin Boline", "Caitlyn McKinzie", "Camella", "Camella Ciabaltino", 
"Candace Conroy", "Capri Leskowicz", "Carlos Castillo", "Carol Sapp", 
"Carole Sapp", "Caroline Gray", "Charnew", "Chelsea Richards", 
"Chelsey Hagar", "Chereka Hamilton", "Chereka Hamilton ", "Christopher Browning", 
"Claire Fairbanks", "Colleen Sheu", "Danielle Weitzel", "Dave Lawson", 
"David Gulden", "Debbie Tyler", "Debra Buis", "Dipti Sharma", 
"Domonique Woods", "Eric Price", "Eva Oberllander", "Fallon Flowers", 
"Gabriella O.", "Golbahar", "Hannah S", "Heather Faurote", "Heather Stamm", 
"Hiba Kaashmiri", "Isha Tali", "Ivy Byun", "Jackie Flynn", "Jackie Tanner", 
"Jacqueline Villasin", "James Bartlett", "Jane Livingston", "Jena Smith", 
"Jennifer Tyler", "Jennifer Zappola", "Joel Anderson", "Jorge", 
"Julia Manhart", "Juliana Ortagus", "Kara Moulton", "Kate", "Kathleen Endorf", 
"Katie Claxton", "Kay Nowak", "Kenny Totten", "Kerry Berner", 
"Kristen Horton", "Kristen Mercadante", "Kristen Mercadantu", 
"Kristen Rigney", "Kristin Falen", "Kristina Snyder", "Krystal Christopher", 
"Lauren P", "Lauren Patterson", "Lauren Thilmony", "Lauren Walker", 
"Lisa Eade", "Mackenzie McAnaough", "Madeline Alt", "Makenzie McAnaugh", 
"Maria Beregkina", "Maya Arth", "Megan Dowdell", "Megan LeClair", 
"Melissa P", "Michelle Nicholson", "Molly Koozer", "Morgana Wojcik", 
"Natasha Sankella", "Nicole Curry", "Nicole Rohner", "Niki Dagot", 
"Nora A", "Pachel Parker", "Rachel Goldberg", "Rachel Irons", 
"Rachel K. ", "Rachel Kosiba", "Rachel Parker", "Rebekah Rosen", 
"Ryan Sever", "Samantha Amick", "Sanya Matani", "Sara Ashley Phillips", 
"Shainna Ali", "Shana King", "Shawn Helvey", "Sherry Lehman", 
"Sim", "Simanto Khandaker", "Sofia Moumouris", "Stephanie Cassidy", 
"Susan M. Riposta", "Susan Riposta", "Tamara Nelson", "Taneisha Greenidge", 
"Tania", "Tara Engold", "Taylor Farrell", "Teddy Moumouris", 
"Thomas Naboris", "Thomas Nabors", "Tiffany Miller", "Tori Cole", 
"Tracy Gammage", "Vanessa Dominguez", "Vanessa Hernandez", "Whitney Abernathy", 
"Zarana Upadhay", "Zarana Upadhyay"), class = "factor"), Taskb = c(24, 
24, 24, 24, 26, 27, 19, 15, 19, 22, 20, 21, 11, 21, 24, 25, 16, 
18, 19, 22, 22, 17, 19, 23, 16, 19, 21, 21, 21, 20, 23, 19, 19, 
27, 20, 16, 20, 23, 23, 27, 20, 21, 25, 21, 22, 25, 23, 24, 22, 
16, 16, 16, 19, 23, 23, 26, 20, 20, 22, 19, 20, 24, 23, 20, 20, 
20, 21, 17, 21, 24, 14, 15, 17, 17, 16, 16, 18, 20, 20, 18, 19, 
8, 20, 21, 23, 21, 22, 25, 16, 24, 26, 27, 18, 28, 13, 20, 20, 
23, 23, 24, 18, 21, 21, 21, 23, 21, 21, 17, 19, 18, 21, 25, 20, 
20, 25, 25, 14, 16, 17, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 17, 19, 27, 21, 15, 
17, 20, 21, 24, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 22, 23, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
21, 21, 22, 24, 18, 25, 23, 23, 24, 18, 23, 23, 24, 21, 24, 22, 
22, 24, 24, 23, 24, 24, 11, 16, 21, 27, 18, 21, 15, 22, 18, 18, 
19, 24, 21, 21, 22, 20, 24, 26, 22, 22, 16, 20, 21, 21, 22, 24, 
20, 22, 20, 20, 24, 25, 22, 22, 21, 27, 23, 25, 25, 25, 25, 22, 
22, 25, 25, 15, 15, 16, 17, 19, 19, 19, 18, 20, 23, 23, 16, 18, 
18, 19, 23, 26, 20, 25, 16, 18, 20, 23, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 20, 
20, 22, 24, 19, 17, 22, 24, 24, 20, 23, 24, 26, 17, 24, 25, 21, 
22, 26, 27, 27, 27, 21, 16, 17, 21, 21, 24, 16, 18, 21, 23, 26, 
28, 8, 15, 19, 20, 16, 23, 23, 24, 27, 24, 24, 26, 19, 19, 23, 
24, 14, 23, 22, 24, 11, 20, 21, 27, 25, 24, 24, 21, 24, 20, 20, 
22, 23, 26, 23, 23, 22, 16, 16, 22, 15, 18, 19, 28, 17, 20, 20, 
18, 20, 20, 13, 15, 19, 21, 20, 21, 21, 11, 20, 23, 25, 22, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Bondb = c(26, 24, 27, 27, 26, 24, 22, 24, 23, 23, 22, 
21, 13, 21, 23, 25, 21, 21, 23, 24, 24, 20, 22, 23, 20, 23, 24, 
24, 24, 19, 23, 19, 19, 27, 20, 20, 20, 23, 23, 28, 25, 24, 25, 
23, 24, 25, 24, 24, 25, 18, 18, 18, 19, 20, 23, 25, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 24, 26, 25, 25, 20, 23, 21, 20, 24, 24, 17, 14, 20, 20, 24, 
16, 23, 21, 23, 20, 24, 13, 25, 22, 24, 24, 22, 26, 21, 24, 21, 
24, 22, 26, 20, 24, 24, 22, 25, 25, 18, 20, 24, 24, 27, 23, 23, 
21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 22, 21, 26, 25, 18, 20, 23, 22, 24, 23, 23, 
26, 22, 16, 19, 25, 22, 21, 24, 23, 24, 23, 25, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 20, 20, 19, 23, 21, 22, 20, 25, 25, 26, 28, 25, 25, 25, 21, 
20, 21, 24, 27, 26, 24, 22, 24, 24, 25, 25, 24, 16, 19, 19, 21, 
18, 23, 24, 22, 19, 23, 23, 24, 21, 21, 22, 26, 23, 27, 24, 24, 
19, 25, 26, 20, 27, 27, 23, 24, 20, 21, 25, 26, 25, 18, 22, 24, 
24, 26, 22, 22, 26, 21, 24, 22, 22, 18, 18, 18, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
24, 25, 25, 25, 23, 23, 23, 24, 27, 27, 26, 25, 19, 21, 22, 25, 
21, 23, 23, 25, 24, 18, 25, 23, 24, 22, 16, 21, 24, 24, 23, 23, 
23, 22, 19, 25, 26, 27, 24, 26, 28, 26, 28, 24, 17, 16, 23, 21, 
23, 22, 23, 21, 26, 27, 27, 10, 16, 20, 23, 21, 23, 23, 26, 27, 
26, 27, 24, 20, 22, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 27, 14, 22, 28, 27, 25, 
24, 24, 18, 23, 21, 21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 26, 24, 23, 23, 23, 18, 
20, 22, 28, 16, 24, 14, 24, 22, 22, 23, 17, 22, 27, 23, 22, 22, 
20, 18, 24, 25, 26, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Goalb = c(23, 23, 24, 24, 18, 
23, 17, 15, 21, 21, 23, 17, 10, 17, 25, 25, 10, 21, 21, 25, 25, 
18, 19, 22, 16, 18, 21, 21, 21, 20, 23, 18, 18, 25, 17, 18, 20, 
25, 23, 27, 21, 24, 23, 20, 22, 24, 25, 25, 24, 17, 17, 17, 18, 
23, 24, 27, 22, 23, 22, 21, 22, 19, 20, 19, 20, 19, 22, 21, 22, 
24, 14, 14, 17, 17, 17, 21, 14, 18, 21, 17, 21, 10, 23, 22, 24, 
24, 22, 24, 14, 26, 22, 25, 19, 27, 15, 19, 19, 22, 23, 23, 18, 
20, 22, 19, 25, 18, 18, 17, 18, 17, 24, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 15, 
14, 22, 19, 21, 18, 20, 24, 17, 19, 23, 20, 14, 20, 18, 19, 24, 
22, 20, 24, 24, 20, 22, 22, 15, 15, 13, 20, 21, 20, 23, 19, 25, 
22, 25, 23, 23, 24, 20, 23, 24, 24, 19, 22, 21, 23, 24, 22, 24, 
23, 24, 9, 14, 17, 28, 18, 21, 11, 18, 17, 20, 19, 23, 21, 21, 
20, 19, 20, 24, 24, 24, 10, 14, 27, 18, 26, 23, 19, 19, 21, 21, 
24, 25, 24, 18, 22, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 26, 21, 22, 25, 25, 17, 
17, 18, 17, 18, 18, 18, 15, 21, 24, 24, 17, 18, 20, 21, 25, 26, 
21, 25, 16, 17, 19, 22, 22, 23, 25, 22, 19, 21, 19, 19, 24, 15, 
16, 22, 20, 20, 23, 26, 26, 27, 15, 24, 27, 16, 22, 27, 28, 23, 
28, 26, 19, 17, 20, 22, 24, 16, 20, 22, 25, 25, 27, 12, 17, 20, 
20, 14, 23, 23, 22, 27, 23, 25, 25, 19, 20, 22, 23, 17, 23, 19, 
26, 7, 16, 22, 25, 24, 24, 24, 23, 24, 20, 20, 19, 25, 26, 24, 
24, 23, 22, 16, 22, 16, 19, 19, 22, 15, 24, 17, 18, 22, 25, 18, 
17, 16, 21, 18, 21, 21, 13, 20, 23, 27, 22, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Name3 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 57L, 56L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
71L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 
81L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 90L, 89L, 91L, 
92L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 
114L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 127L, 128L, 128L, 129L, 129L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
150L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 156L, 155L, 157L, 158L, 
159L, 159L, 160L, 160L, 161L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 
167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 175L, 176L, 
177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 185L, 186L, 
187L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("Adam Tharkur", 
"Adam Tharkur ", "Alan Hamaoui", "Alan Hamaoui ", "Alyssa Bassani", 
"Alyssa Sorrells", "Alyssa Sorrells ", "Amanda Perez", "Amarillis Garcia", 
"Amarillus Garcia ", "Amber Norman", "Amy Valentino ", "Anastasia Motillal", 
"Andre Gutierrez3H", "Andrea du Chausse", "Andrea Scott", "Angel McNeil", 
"Angel McNeil ", "April Kouri", "Ariella Sherman", "Ashley 2C", 
"Ashley Westfall", "Aubrey Gainey", "Brandon Vieira", "Brianna Franklin", 
"Britani Hall ", "Britani Hall6G", "Brittany Bodnick", "Brittany Bodnick ", 
"Brittany Jones5E", "Caitlin Boline", "Caitlin Boline ", "Caitlyn McKinzie", 
"Caitlyn Mckinzie ", "Camella Ciabattoni", "Candice Conroy", 
"Capri Leszkowicz", "Capri Leszkowicz ", "Carole Sapp", "Carole Sapp ", 
"Caroline Gray", "Caroline Grey", "Carolos Castillo", "Chelsea Richards", 
"Chelsey Hagar", "Chereka Hamilton", "Chereka Hamilton ", "Christopher Browning", 
"Claire Fairbanks", "Cody Kimmel", "Cody Kimmell", "Collen Sheu", 
"Danielle Weitzel", "David Gulden", "David Lawson", "Daylin Rivero", 
"Daylin Rivero ", "Debbie Alexander", "Debra Buis", "Dipti Sharma", 
"Dipti Sharma ", "Dominque Woods ", "Emily Bone", "Eric Price", 
"Esmeralda Charneco", "Eva Oberleander ", "Eva Oberlender", "Fallon Flowers", 
"Fallon Flowers ", "Gabriela Oropeza", "Hannah Smith", "Heather Faurote", 
"Heather Faurote ", "Heather Pritsker", "Heather Stam ", "Heather Stamm", 
"Hgolbahar Eftekhari", "Hiba Kaashmiri", "Isha Talati", "Ivy Byun", 
"Jackie Tanner ", "Jacqueline Flynn", "Jacqueline Villasin", 
"James Barlett ", "James Bartlett", "Jamie Holmquist", "Jane Livingston", 
"Jena Smith", "Jennifer Tyler", "Jennifer Tyler ", "Jennifer Zapppola", 
"Joel Anderson", "Jorge Lopez", "Julia Manhart", "Juliana Ortagus", 
"Kaitlin Magersuppe", "Kara Moulton", "Katelyn Judge", "Katherine Claxton", 
"Kathleen Endorf", "Kathrina Cann", "Kathrine Cann", "Katie Claxton", 
"Kay Nowak ", "Kay Nowak1F", "Kenneth Totten", "Kenny Totten", 
"Kerrie Taylor", "Kerry Berner", "Kristen Bresnihan", "Kristen Horton", 
"Kristen Mercadante ", "Kristen Rigney", "Kristin Falen", "Kristina Snyder", 
"Krystal Christopher", "Lauran Patterson", "Lauran Walker", "Lauren Patterson", 
"Lauren Patterson ", "Lauren Thilmony", "Lauren Thilmony ", "Leslie Eastman", 
"Lindsay Weinstock", "Lisa Eade", "Lisa Marie Ramkissoon-Dawson", 
"Madeline Alt", "Makenzie McAnaugh", "Maria Berezkina", "Marliese Carmona", 
"Maya Arth ", "Maya Arth2H", "Megan Dowdell", "Megan Leclair", 
"Melissa Ford", "Michelle Nicholson ", "Michelle Nicholson2E", 
"Molly Koozer", "Morgana Wojcik ", "Naseema Abbasi", "Natasha Sankella", 
"Nick Ciancioso", "Nicole Curry ", "Nicole Rohrer", "Nikki Dagot", 
"Noelle Neemeh ", "Noelle Nemmeh", "Nora Alkhatib", "Pamela Leonard ", 
"Rachel Goldberg", "Rachel Irons", "Rachel Kosiba", "Rachel parker", 
"Rachel Parker", "Rebekah Rosen", "Rebekah Rosen ", "Renee Hudson", 
"Ruby Coopersmith", "Ryan Sever", "Samantha Amick", "Sanya Matani", 
"Sara Ashley Phillips", "Shana King", "Shana King ", "Shawn Helvey", 
"Sherry Lehman", "Sigrid Monie Wire", "Simanto K.", "Simanto Khandak", 
"Simanto Khandaker", "Sofia Moumouris", "Stephanie Cassidy ", 
"Susan M. Riposta ", "Susan Riposta ", "Tamara Nelson", "Taneisha Greenidge", 
"Tania Alidina", "Tara Dallaire4C", "Tara Engold", "Taylor Farrell", 
"Taylor Farrell ", "Teddy Moumouris", "Thomas Naboris ", "Thomas Nabors", 
"Tiffany Miller", "Tori Cole", "Tracy Gammage", "Vanessa Dominguez", 
"Vanessa Dominguez ", "Vanessa Hernandez ", "Vanessa Roca ", 
"Whitney Abernath ", "Zarana Upadhyay"), class = "factor"), Rapport = c(4.08, 
6.08, 5.5, 7, 7, 6.58, 5.67, 5.42, 5.42, 6.83, 5.83, 6.67, 6.5, 
6.92, 4, 5.75, 6.33, 6.25, 6.17, 6.75, 5, 3.83, 5.08, 6.58, 6.33, 
6.5, 6.83, 6.75, 6.08, 6.58, 4.67, 5.83, 4.83, 6.08, 6.5, 4.83, 
6.42, 6.92, 5.17, 5.75, 5.67, 5.92, 7, 3.42, 4.25, 5.58, 6.92, 
6.58, 6.42, 5.67, 5.5, 6.5, 5.33, 5.92, 6.83, 6.08, 6.17, 4.58, 
6.42, 5.67, 5.92, 5.58, 6.08, 5.08, 7, 5.67, 6.92, 7, 6.58, 3.92, 
6.08, 6.25, 4.58, 6.42, 5.75, 6.75, 6.58, 3.83, 6.83, 4.17, 6.58, 
5.92, 5.33, 4.83, 4.58, 6.42, 5.67, 7, 6.5, 5.42, 3.75, 5, 3.25, 
5.5, 5.25, 6.75, 6.92, 6.5, 5.67, 7, 6.17, 5.5, 6.67, 6.83, 6, 
6.33, 6.75, 6.92, 6.75, 5, 6.92, 6.75, 6.17, 5.92, 6.83, 6.33, 
4.75, 4.58, 7, 6.58, 3.75, 6.58, 6.5, 4.5, 6.25, 7, 6.33, 6.08, 
6, 6.92, 5.33, 6.33, 3.75, 5.92, 6.33, 6.17, 6.83, 6.75, 6.58, 
6.92, 5.83, 5.42, 6.58, 6.33, 4.42, 6.58, 6.67, 6.67, 6.67, 6.17, 
2.42, 6.25, 5.5, 6, 6.83, 7, 5.83, 3.67, 6.75, 6.83, 5.67, 6.42, 
6.17, 6.67, 5.83, 6.75, 6.17, 6.5, 5.42, 6.83, 6.58, 6.5, 6.83, 
5.08, 5.58, 6.25, 6.5, 4.92, 6.5, 5, 5.17, 4.75, 7, 6.67, 6.83, 
6.58, 6.42, 6.25, 6.58, 6.75, 6.17, 6.83, 5.33, 6.92, 1.67, 6.83, 
6.33, 5, 6.83, 5.92, 6.42, 5.67, 4.92, 6.25, 6.17, 6.58, 6.58, 
6.5, 6.67, 4.33, 6, 6.67, 5.08, 7, 6.75, 6, 6.75, 6.58, 5.83, 
6.67, 6.83, 6.33, 5, 5.75, 5.75, 5.17, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Client = c(4.29, 
6, 6.29, 6.43, 6.57, 6, 5.29, 5, 4.71, 5.71, 5.29, 5.57, 6, 6.43, 
5.14, 5.71, 6, 6.29, 6.43, 6.71, 5, 5.43, 3.86, 6.86, 6.14, 6.14, 
6.71, 6, 6.29, 6.71, 4.14, 6, 5, 5.86, 6.29, 4.29, 6.57, 6.86, 
5.14, 5.86, 5.71, 6, 7, 4.57, 3.14, 4.86, 6.57, 6.86, 6.57, 6.14, 
6.29, 6.43, 5.86, 5.57, 6.43, 6, 6.14, 4.86, 6.14, 5.29, 5.43, 
4.86, 5, 4.29, 6.86, 5.71, 6.86, 7, 6.86, 5.14, 6.29, 6, 2.86, 
5.57, 6, 6.71, 6.43, 4.57, 7, 4.43, 6.86, 4.57, 6.43, 4.57, 4.43, 
5.86, 5.29, 7, 6.43, 5.29, 4.29, 4.29, 3.71, 5.43, 6, 6.86, 7, 
6.29, 6, 7, 5.71, 5.86, 6.57, 6.86, 5.57, 6, 6.14, 6.57, 7, 5.57, 
6.86, 6.57, 5.86, 7, 6.86, 6.86, 4.43, 5.57, 7, 6.43, 3.14, 6.86, 
5.57, 4.43, 6.57, 7, 5.71, 5.86, 5.71, 6.57, 5.29, 6.29, 4.71, 
6.14, 5.86, 6.29, 6.29, 6.71, 6.43, 7, 5.71, 6.43, 6.29, 6, 5, 
6.57, 6.71, 6.71, 4.29, 5.71, 2.43, 7, 5.29, 5.86, 6, 7, 6.29, 
4.29, 6.43, 6.86, 5, 5.86, 6.14, 5.86, 5.71, 7, 6, 6.14, 5.43, 
6.57, 5.71, 6.43, 6.43, 5, 5.29, 5.43, 6, 3.43, 4.86, 4.57, 5.57, 
5.57, 7, 6.86, 6.86, 5.86, 6.43, 5.43, 6.43, 6.14, 6.43, 6.43, 
4, 7, 3, 7, 6, 5.29, 7, 5.57, 6.57, 5.57, 5.57, 6.43, 6, 6.14, 
6, 5.86, 6.57, 5, 6.14, 5.86, 3.86, 6.71, 7, 6.29, 7, 6.86, 5.29, 
6.57, 6.71, 6.43, 5.43, 5.14, 5.86, 5.71, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Name1", 
"Taska", "Bonda", "Goala", "Name2", "Taskb", "Bondb", "Goalb", 
"Name3", "Rapport", "Client"), row.names = c(NA, -355L), class = "data.frame")
```

Above is my dataframe. It is actually three dataframes combined together.

What I am intending to have is something like this: where each name has **only one row**, and the values are the **mean** values from each column. Do anyone know how to do that?

[image: Intended Outcome]

Comment: Please don't post an image, instead use `dput` to show the first few lines of your dataset.  If you have the `Name` column duplicated, just remove the duplicate columns and use `aggregate` or `dplyr`

Comment: @akrun Thank you and I have posted the dput. Frankly this is my first time using dput. I tried your code, and the problem is there are different number of entries of name in each column.

Comment: I updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: Could you please update with a reproducible `dput` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
lst <- split(1:ncol(df1),cumsum(grepl('Name', colnames(df1))))
lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(i) {x1 <- na.omit(df1[i])
             colnames(x1)[1] <- 'Name'
             aggregate(.~ Name, x1, mean)})

res <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='Name', all=TRUE), lst2)
head(res,2)
#          Name Taska Bonda Goala Taskb Bondb Goalb Rapport Client
#1 Adam Tharker  24.0  24.0  24.0    24  26.0  23.0      NA     NA
#2 Adam Tharkur  26.6  26.6  26.4    25  25.6  22.4    4.08   4.29

dim(res)
#[1] 262   9
```

Comment: It gets exactly what I want. Thanks!